# Accessing local database from android phone using mobile tethering

Tags: laravel, localhost, android-studio-3.0

I'm developing an mobile attendance application and I want to submit the data gathered from my phone to my web-based application in my laptop. Is there any way I can submit those data using only mobile tethering?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a private network and set up a VPN on your phone to access that network